# I'm doing simple integration of Mongodb and springboot, but unable to save data properly

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm fairly new to java and spring boot. I'm trying to save data in mongo through spring, but it only saves _id=0 and model class.
My controller

```
package com.example.usermanagement.resource;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.usermanagement.model.User;
import com.example.usermanagement.repository.userRepository;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private userRepository repository;
    
    @PostMapping("/saveUser")
    public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user){
         System.out.println(user);
         repository.save(user); 
         return "User Added";
        
    }   
    @GetMapping("/findAllUsers")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/findAllUsers{id}")
    public Optional<User> getUser(@PathVariable int id){
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable int id){
        repository.deleteById(id);
        return "User Deleted";
    }   
    

}
On hitting save through postman, I get this in my db
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

My model

```
package com.example.usermanagement.model;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

@Document(collection = "user_data")
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id; 
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

And the repository

```
package com.example.usermanagement.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.usermanagement.model.User;

@Repository
public interface userRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

[image]

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong here, Why the rest of the data is not getting saved properly also Id is coming 0 rather than what I'm sending.

Post request I'm sending

```
{
    "id":2,
    "name":"yash",
    "lastName":"asd",
    "role":"dev"
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? And you have to increase the id if you use int for id field

Comment: No I do not get any error, post request happens succesfully. But as you can see in the last image only id and class is visible. Also, I'm sending the id in the post request.

Comment: show us the request body u sent

Comment: I have edited the response for the request I'm sending

Comment: try sending like this `{
    "id":2,
    "firstName":"yash",
    "lastName":"asd"
}`

Comment: let me know if its woring, i will explain

Comment: Yeah, I got it why you asked. Its not working. Role should be there in the model. I was editing lot of stuff so last save must have been that. I have in controller in saveUser as you can see have put a print statement. "com.example.usermanagement.model.User@23cd50f6" this is what gets printed there. Also the error comes for duplicate key for id when we post the second time as 0 is the id every time for some reason

Comment: Its ok, change to `System.out.println(user.toString())` and remove all data from db and check again

Comment: Same kind of output, I think its a memory location if I'm not wrong. And in the snapshot as I have posted of db I think it just contains id and class

Comment: Doesn't it print System.out.println(user.toString())???

Comment: It prints "com.example.usermanagement.model.User@2e79ccec" even after doing toString()

Comment: fine then. try `user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName()`

Comment: So getters and setters of lombok was not working, I manually generated them . And its working now. Please post the answer so that I can accept. Thanks a lot, I was pulling my hair for a long time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dont use `@Field` to notify to database, you need to pass the same model class name as parameters.

```
{
    "id":2,
    "firstName":"yash",
    "lastName":"asd"
}
```

Lombok won't automatically be configured. So you need to manually configure. [Setting up lombok](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide)